# Google static map tile service - how to map between pixels and latitude / longitude?

Tags: google-maps, maps

Google provides a static map tile service. These are those 256x256 static map tiles. Do they provide a library that maps latitude,longitudes to pixel coordinates, and vice versa? I see some implementations of this around the web, but wondering if they have an official implementation that can be used.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, I can't find any documentation about the Google Tile Service: is it available for the satellite layer too?

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check method "fromLatLngToDivPixel" https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference#GMap2.fromLatLngToDivPixel

It takes latlng:GLatLng as argument and returns GPoint reference.

Comment: That API is deprecated and you can't use fromLatLngToDivPixel on v3 without having a map. Meaning that , if i want to use static map i don't have to use any API.